# How do I credit a quote if I am uncertain of the source?

Tags: publishing, quotes

If I am writing a book and want to use a quote, but I either don't remember who said it or I am uncertain, how should I credit the quote?

Comment: say the quote and then say {by unknown} or something.

Comment: Don't. You can write "unknown" or "anonymous" only for those who actually have no certain attribution. For anything else you must give credentials.

Comment: Try using google.  regardless if someone said it or if it is unknown, it will pop up in your search.

Comment: Are you even sure it is a quote?

Comment: Lots of quotes are attributed incorrectly on the internet. Usually to Einstein...

Comment: "Everything you read on the internet is true" - Abraham Lincoln..... But seriously for actual quotes that aren't memes, there is a ton of quote sites with references for sources to use.  If you spend days trolling reddit and facebook, yes, a lot of them are purposely done incorrectly...

Answer (score 4):

The first order of business is to acknowledge the quote as someone else's work and not your own by putting quotation marks around it. "I think therefore I am."*

The second thing to do is to cite the type of source, even if you don't know the exact one. "As she said in a song from an old movie, 'I'm as corny as Kansas in August.'"

Then you go on a site like Movies and Film SE (or Quora) and ask, "What old movie does the following line of an old song come from?"

And hopefully, you'll get the answer: ("I'm in Love With a Wonderful Guy," *South Pacific,* Rodgers and Hammerstein.)

*Descartes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing a book and not a blog, better search more and try to find out who said it.

If you are still unable to get the result, go for "unknown" or "a wise man/woman once said...".

Answer (score 1):

If your book is fiction then you have the option of attributing the quote to an unreliable character then having another character recognize the mistake either publicly or in internal/thought dialogue.

For example, have your antagonist credit Shakespeare for "I think therefore I am" then have your protagonist thinking, "What an idiot!  That's not Shakespeare!".

Your protagonist is not then required to provide correct attribution.  A change in the scene might distract them, leaving the attribution uncorrected.